# Is there a way to push data to a stream without loosing it's content?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an infinite scroll with a StreamBuilder on Flutter with Firestore. While I've managed to retrieve everything I needed on the initial load (let's say 10 first posts), I can't manage to add data from the next page to the initial Stream.

I've a Stream called "content", where I've put my initial fetched post but when I'm trying to add some other content to this Stream, it get's erased by the content added when I'm doing `mystream.sink.add(data)` How can I keep the initial Stream's content and ADD the new content to the Stream?

Here is some code:

In my view:

```
 body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.documentData, // My initial Stream in my view
```

In my controller / bloc (FeedController):

```
 FeedController() {
    loadInitialFeed();
 }

final _documentData = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get documentData => _documentData.stream;


loadInitialFeed() async {
    QuerySnapshot test = await _database.test(await _user.getSecuredUserId());
    _documentData.sink.add(test);
}
```

In fact, what I'm looking for is simply a way to merge two Streams. I've been looking since this morning...

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly but you may think that streams are a data structure which is not so you may need to make a list and add to it all your fetched records (old+new) then add it to the stream!.

Comment: Yes, based on your answer I think you got the idea of what I want to do lol. In fact, I think, you're right I think the list may be a better way, I even managed to get it working with a list but the code is not clean enough for me (too much logic code in the view). 

I finally managed to get it working with the Streambuilder by simply using Firestore's caching feature: I first load X Posts, and then when reaching the bottom of the screen I'm reloading actual Stream with Y more posts by simply passing the actual total number of posts to my request with the limit parameter. Works like a charm.

Comment: Great!, have a look here to make sure that you are doing this the right way https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm not using the starAfter condition, only the limit one. I've been thinking: as Firestore's store in cache for 30 minutes the retrieved data on the device, why should I not use this capacity? I can relaunch my request without being billed for document reads as the data are already in cache. 

In the case of "ListView", yes, the starAfter condition is a must use :)

Comment: I understand your argument but as long as you are sure that the server data does not change during this 30 min you are fine :)